# Reusing UNIX sockets with Twisted over multiple processes

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, unix-socket

I am trying to implement a Twisted server made up of multiple processes which all listen on a UNIX socket. I have tried enabling the SO_REUSEADDR and SO_REUSEPORT options for the socket and used the following endpoint: unix:address=/tmp/web.sock:lockfile=0.

This works fine with one process, however, when I spawn multiple ones, there still seems to be only one listening on that socket. Is there something I am doing wrong in my current setup?

Comment: typically each process will have a single unix socket which you would load balance between

Answer (score 1):

You can't share a UNIX socket by binding it multiple times.  Instead, bind it once and share the resulting file descriptor across all of the processes.

You can do this using Twisted's [adoptStreamPort](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IReactorSocket.html) API ([UNIX socket support was added in 2017](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5573)).